# Working with negative values inside a structure

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a structure called "variable" with the following contents.

1. There are some negative values inside every field of vectors. I would like to keep the value but make it positive.
2. Make a new variable say **v11** (a 1633X1 double), having an element wise average of the fields.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`abs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) with [`structfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to convert values to positive. Then use [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) and horizontally concatenate the cell contents to apply [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and assign the result to the new field `v11`.

```
variable = structfun(@abs,variable,'un',0);
v11= struct2cell(variable);
variable.v11=mean([v11{:}],2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!